# Finding an IHTMLelement from web document containg <Class="submit" .......> using Delphi 2006?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

In a `TWebBrowser` application I want to get a pointer to the element containing this element, using Delphi 2006 (!)

```html
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="&nbsp;Vis veibeskrivelse&nbsp;" onclick="showDirections();" />
<a href="#" onclick="openDirections(); return false;">&Aring;pne veibeskrivelse i Google Maps</a>
<br />
```

I find that `IHTMLDocument7` implements a `getElementsByClassName`, but in Delphi 2006, the `IHTMLDocument7` is not implemented.

Are there other means on getting the pointer to this element?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `IHTMLDocument7` interface manually in your code, it is just an interface declaration.  Delphi does not actually implement the interface, the web browser does.

Otherwise, since the element does not have a name, you can loop through the `IHTMLDocument.all` collection one element at a time, querying the `className` property of each element until you find what you are looking for.

Comment: ok.there is not so many element, so I'll tru the ,akk method :-)

Thx!